# Is there any chance system.h file I made for my C programing assignment caused problems to my OS?

Tags: c, operating-system

I'm currently doing an assignment in C, and a day after I made a file called "system.h" my OS started making problems (I recived an error message then computer crashed).. it didn't end so well, but I'm still interested.
could it be the name of the file that made this whole mess happen?

Comment: Including a header file shouldn't make your program crash. If not including it doesn't prevent compilation then it wasn't needed in the first place. When you get "an error message", please, please, **because we're not psychic**, include it in your question.

Comment: **Definitely** nothing to do with the name.  The OS would stop you from compiling the file if it was going to damage it.

Comment: potentially inclusion of a header file which contains definitions of variables or function can change layout of the compiled code. So, if you already have an undetected memory corruption in the program, it could now cause a crash of the program. If you run on an ancient operating system or under root/admin privs, potentially it could cause a crash of the os as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged in as an unprivileged user on a system with proper multi-user management (e.g., macOS, Linux, other Unix systems), **nothing** you do without privileges should affect the operating system. (If the operating system is affected, there is a bug in the operating system.)

If you have privileged access to the system, then making a file called “system.h” in your own area should not, by itself, affect the operating system. Compiling a program using that header and running the program will not affect the system (unless the program runs with privileges and does something to affect the system, but that is unrelated to what the name of the header file is).

If you modified files belonging to the system, then you can affect the operating system.